# How do I use find to copy all found files to a new name in their same directories?

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp, xargs

I've got a simple command that does almost what I want.  The following will locate all files with a suffix of '_compressed.swf' and copy each into its same directory with a '.bak2' appended:

find '../content' -name '*_compressed.swf' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} {}.bak2

**Results**
In:  /content/somefile_compressed.swf
Out: /content/somefile_compressed.swf.bak2

However, I need to replace '_compressed.swf' with '_content.swf'  I'd like to use find, rather than recursive flag on cp for consistency.

**Objective**
In:  /content/somefile_compressed.swf
Out: /content/somefile_content.swf

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/115880/how-do-i-use-find-to-copy-all-found-files-to-a-new-name-in-their-same-directories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is probably the most portable:

```
find "../content" -name "*_compressed.swf" -exec sh -c 'cp {} `dirname {}`/`basename {} compressed.swf`content.swf' \;
```

There is also the famous [rename.pl](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Rename.pl) script which is  distributed with Perl, and the [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command which could have made this a bit easier. These aren't available on all distributions though, these commands are for the most part.

Comment: The above moves the files from their current location to the script's location and adds the suffix 'content.swf'.  Replacing mv with cp gets me closer, but I still need replace text in name rather than append.  I'm getting closer by using sed, but still learning.

Comment: @Michael you're right! whoops. I was only testing in the current directory hence why it worked for me. I've fixed it :)

Comment: Hey, thanks John.  I like it.  Much of this is all new to me.  I understand usage of find, -exec, sh, dirname {}, basename {}, but I'm a little confused about the combined usage.  sh -c ' ' converts the string into a command and runs the command, right?  mv {} expands into one of find results "mv ../content/file1of20_compressed.swf ???????"  It's the second part of that which I don't understand yet.  What is causing the compressed.swf to be replaced by content.swf?  In my solution you can see I just learned how to use sed.

Comment: @Michael what's happening is the file is being moved with a new name. If `{}` contained `/etc/somefile_compressed.swf`, dirname takes `/etc` and `basename {} compressed.swf` will leave you with `somefile_`. Now you put these 2 together with the slash I added in the middle (`/`) and you have `/etc/somefile_`. You'll notice I added `content.swf` to the end so it completes the statement as `/etc/somefile_content.swf`. HTH.

Comment: i'd use *rename.pl* if *mv* functionality was desired (it's not hard to add to any system with Perl) but the *cp* makes this a different beast.  you'd have to tweak the script to do a copy instead of rename, which would work, but is more work.  @John - nice *find* solution; it's big and long and ugly, but it looks like it would work.  (don't ask me to help test it tho!)  :)

Comment: @~quack I totally missed out on the cp part! fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this all can be handled in one line. I got really close to a one line solution and with some help even closer, but no success.  The following works:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read all file names into an array
FilesArray=($(find "../content" -name "*_compressed.swf"))

# Get length of an array
FilesIndex=${#FilesArray[@]}


# Use for loop read all directory names
for (( i=0; i<${FilesIndex}; i++ ));
do
    source="${FilesArray[$i]}"
    destination="$(echo "${source}" | sed 's/compressed/content/')"
    cp "${source}" "${destination}"
done

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick and is collapsible to a one liner if you really really need to ;)

```
find ../content -name '*_compressed.swf' | while read file
do
cp "$file" "${file/_compressed.swf/_content.swf}"
done
```

Bash pattern substitution works nicely in these cases.